# PHP Pretty URLs combination of two mod_rewrite rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have this .htaccess code in the root folder to replace this url: `localhost/mysite/profile.php?username="someone"` to become `localhost/mysite/someone`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/profile.php?username=$1
```

This is working fine but what I want is to include subpages like for example the **about** page to be `localhost/mysite/about` instead of `localhost/mysite/about.php`. And the subpages are in the root folder too.

How can I achieve these two rewrites?

Comment: Is this .htaccess located in `mysite/` directory?

Comment: yes, in localhost/mysite. Where the index.php and about.php are located.

Comment: FWIW... "replace this url: `localhost/mysite/profile.php?username="someone"` to become `localhost/mysite/someone`" - it seems many people often use this _reverse-like_ description (?), but your code actually does the complete opposite.... `/mysite/someone` is rewritten to become `/mysite/profile.php?username=someone`. (?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this code in `mysite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /mysite/

# add .php internally to files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# handles profile URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Wow that was quick sir! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it's working fine to me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It works for subpages but the other one was replaced and it's not working now which is **localhost/mysite/user123** from this **localhost/mysite/profile.php?username=username123**

Comment: This would conflict with the existing directives (regardless of order). You would need to include a _condition_ to exclude URLs that look like user profiles (ie. URLs that don't match to physical files directly).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mysite/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /mysite/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: Sorry both are not working now. @anubhava already answered my question. Thanks guys! :)